# How to randomize the order of DISTINCT ON results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table of podcast episodes

```
id | title | podcast_id | publication_date
 1 |   "a" |          1 |            today
 2 |   "b" |          2 |            today
 3 |   "c" |          1 |            yesterday
 4 |   "d" |          2 |            yesterday
```

With this query I can the latest episode from each podcast.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (episodes.podcast_id) episodes.* FROM "episodes"
WHERE ...
ORDER BY episodes.podcast_id, "episodes"."publication_date" DESC
```

Results in

```
id | title | podcast_id | publication_date
 1 |   "a" |          1 |            today
 2 |   "b" |          2 |            today
```

I'd like to randomize the order of the podcasts returned, so that `podcast_id` 2 might be returned before 1, but adding `RANDOM()` to the final `ORDER BY` clause changes which episode for the given podcast is chosen.

To summarize: I want the newest episodes from each podcast in a random order.

Edit: I should mention that this query is the result of chaining many ActiveRecord scopes together. Here is the final answer translated to ActiveRecord

```
# This ActiveRecord statement is equivalent to the above SQL query
episodes = Episode
  .unscoped
  .select("DISTINCT ON (episodes.podcast_id) episodes.*")
  .order("episodes.podcast_id, episodes.publication_date")

Episode
  .unscoped
  .from("(#{sql.to_sql}) episodes")
  .order("random()")
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it. The advantages as I see them are

1. Single query
2. Result is ActiveRecord_Relation, you can continue to chain `limit` or `pluck`

Comment: Why not do it in your code, once the result is obtained from the database?

Comment: This is a ruby on rails project, I find it best to keep queries in ActiveRecord territory for as long as possible so that LIMITs, OFFSETs WHEREs, or SELECTs can be added later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (episodes.podcast_id) episodes.*
    FROM "episodes"
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY episodes.podcast_id, "episodes"."publication_date" DESC
) s
order by random()
```

Comment: I understand that this uses a subquery, but what is the `s` on the penultimate line?

Comment: This is right, I should have tagged this with rails or ActiveRecord because I'm not sure the clean way to form this query in ActiveRecord without writing raw sql.

Comment: @everett1992 Every subquery must have an alias so the `s`

Comment: +1 I thought of this approach and wasn't ultimately sure about the end-issue. Does this work as intended by the OP?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Yes it does.